# How do i run debugger and set break points in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging

I have recently started learning how to use android studio and need to know how to set break points and run the debugger. I clicked on the small button with the insect but it seems to open the emulator just like the green play button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click in the area between your code and the package explorer (with all the directories) to set breakpoints.